# Owin Facebook Login failure on MVC Azure Production site ONLY

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, azure-cloud-services

The short version:

I have an MVC5 website app deployed as an Azure cloud service web role. Using Owin for a login flow.  The Owin Facebook integration works fine when testing the site on localhost, but on the production server GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() is returning null in the callback from signin-facebook.

Some details:

- Have all the latest Owin Nuget packages (4.0.1 other than Identity.Owin 2.2.2 and Owin (startup components) 1.0).
- The app uses basic Owin cookie authentication (traditional logins work fine).
- We are not using the default Owin SigninManager, or UserManager as per the MVC WebApplication template. (Failure occurs well before reaching any of that code, in theory!)
- Testing using Chrome on Windows 10.
- It works perfectly on localhost (both debug and release), directly running the web project from visual studio (no cloud service involvement).
- Am using the same Facebook test user for both localhost and production.
- On the Facebook end, everything looks normal and the app is added to the user's list of apps, with all the permissions.  It's not a facebook rejection.
- Went so far as to remove Application Insights (as that is something different in production), but it did not affect the problem.

Looking at DevTools in Chrome:

- Cache control looks normal for everything, all no-cache.
- The .AspNet.Correlation.Facebook cookie is set and is being returned (same value) to the signin-facebook endpoint on completion from Facebook. Note that there is no other Owin related cookie.

Re. Deployment:

- The Azure cloud service consists of the single web role.
- Azure cloud service osFamily="5" osVersion="*"
- Deployment is done directly from Visual Studio to the staging slot (right click publish).
- I typically perform an interactive login to the staging slot, and when things are warmed up I use the Azure portal to swap the slots.  Testing of the Facebook login is only on the production slot (not staging).

Here is a code fragment showing the processing (ChallengeResult is per the current WebApplication template code). The Controller is marked as [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)] and is not marked for [Authorize]:

```
    // POST: /Membership/ExternalSignupDispatch (They clicked to login with Facebook, Google, etc.)
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalSignupDispatch(string provider, string community = Communities.Dating)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalSignupCallback1", "Membership", new { community }));
    }

    // GET: /Membership/ExternalSignupCallback
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalSignupCallback1(string community = Communities.Dating)
    {
        var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null) // Unsuccessful login
        {
```

The silent failure of Owin/Facebook on the production server is maddening.  If only there were an error enumeration... or an exception... but alas

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So.  It turns out that Owin will currently fail in mysterious manners if there is no pre-existing ASP.NET_SessionID cookie present.  Without it, the signin-facebook function does not remove the .Aspnet.Correlation.Facebook cookie, and does not set the .Aspnet.ExternalCookie cookie. The non-presence of the Session ID cookie somehow prevents the required cookie processing from taking place.  All this sets the stage for intermittent silent failures, depending on the client's cookie status.

The workaround is to store a fake Session variable when generating the form with the Facebook login, forcing creation of the SessionID cookie prior to any Owin logins.

Note we are using the SystemWebCookieManager (in the hopes of avoiding such cookie issues).  It appears that things are still evolving.

For reference, here is the cookie setup in our ConfigureAuth function:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(), 
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Params.LoginExpiryMinutes), 
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider // Used to allow returning 401 Unauthorized status to API calls, instead of 302 redirect
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                {
                    if (!IsAjaxRequest(ctx.Request))
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```